# Ubuntu not able to mount windows hard drive even windows shut down properly in dual boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

My question is about Ubuntu-16.04.
It's showing error -

> Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/***/New Volume: Command-line `mount
>   -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda5" "/media/harshit/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit
>   status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata
>   kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda5':
>   Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state.
>   Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast
>   restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: [Disabling `Fast Startup`](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/757139) for  Windows solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix that problem you can run from Linux

```
ntfsfix /dev/sda5
```

By any chance did you created that partition by Clonzila?
If yes there some issue with it you must use partclone.ntfs for Microsoft partition.

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens because since W8, when you turn off Windows, it is really doing some kind of a hibernation (it keeps information of the status of processes from the last session ), this for giving the user a faster Windows start experience. This is why you have this error. All you have to do to avoid this is just hit "restart" instead of "turn off" from within Windows.

If you want to know more of this Windows feature, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/distinguishing-fast-startup-from-wake-from-hibernation)